# How to click all buttons of a specific class with one button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**The buttons that i want to click with one button.**
The following button are created with every file upload so thats why it is buttons.

```js
var td4=row.insertCell(-1);
td4.innerHTML="<a type='button' class='delete-button' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='Attachment_Remove(this)'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i> delete</a>";
```

**What i want:**
I want to have a button created in js and then when i click that button it should click all buttons of the upper class.

**What i have tried:**

```js
// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("onclick", "divFunction()");

function divFunction(){
   var a = document.getElementsByClassName('delete-button');
   for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++)  
       a[i].click();  
}

// 2. Append somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: What is expected result? What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: the expected result is the button that is being created by js should click all "links i.e currently a".I have tried but its not working.

Comment: Can you describe "not working"? What should occur when each `<a>` element is  clicked?

Comment: Basically <a> link is present in front of every uploaded file when we click on it it removes the uploaded file now what i am seeking is to achieve a "delete all function" when each <a> is clicked with one button every file that is currently uploaded is removed.

Comment: Again, what is issue with `javascript` at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why do you need to dispatch `click` event to all `<a>` elements? How are files uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that does the job:

```
const addAButtonThatClicksAllButtons = () => {

    const button = document.createElement('button');

    button.onclick = () => 
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('delete-button'))
            .forEach(btn => btn.click());

    document.body.appendChild(button);

};
```

It might be cleaner if you use jQuery:

```
const addAButtonThatClicksAllButtons = () => {

    const button = $('<button/>').click(
        () => $('delete-button').click()
    );

    $('body').append(button);

};
```

Comment: @charlietfl _"note that `from()` has limited browser support "_ Do you mean no support at ie?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, others also, older mobile browsers for example

Comment: @charlietfl Why would ie still be used unless user is in environment where they are unable to get most recent version of a FOSS browser? By "others" do you mean chrome/chromium <45, firefox <32, safari <9? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: @guest271314 IE is not gone and still has significant market share. Lots of non technical people have no idea about other browser differences, or have used IE for so long and trust Microsoft and lots of legacy business environments don't allow install of external apps. Same for older mobiles...not everyone upgrades every year

Comment: @charlietfl Unfortunate. Though revealing. After all the litigation as to monopoly several years ago, a legacy of the monopoly still exists.

Comment: @guest271314 also human nature... if they have used something for many years why change ... as in *"if it's not broken...don't fix it"* ?

Comment: @charlietfl Would not describe that as human nature, but of shrewd marketing several years ago. chromium is FOSS. Though perhaps some do not concern themselves with FOSS

Comment: @guest271314 of course they don't....they use what is convenient. Most people are non technical to the point of not knowing what the differences are ... and lots  simply can't switch even if they wanted to. Corporate IT departments can be extremely rigid

Comment: @charlietfl _"Most people are non technical"_ Would be surprised by observing all of the people, from young to old, who are straining their necks to peck at their little mobile devices ubiquitously and incessantly. Those corporate IT depts. which are still using ie must have management on the take. There is no reason to use ie at all at this day and age.

Comment: @guest271314 big difference between user vs understanding the underlying technology. Majority are users that only need to know the UI....not what developers know that drives the UI